# Получить число после зяпятой

Tags: javascript

Есть число `256.52`, как получить оставшееся число после точки?

```js
var number = 256.52;

console.log(parseInt(number)) // тут получили целое число
```

Comment: какой результат ожидается в итоге?

Comment: @Grundy результат `52`

Comment: А после точки может быть сколько угодно цифр или только две?

Comment: @Grundy, извиняюсь за долгий ответ, после точки может быть сколько угодной цифр.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function fractionAsInt(value) {
  var str = ("" + value).split(".")[1];
  return str? +str : 0;
}

console.log(fractionAsInt(256.52));
console.log(fractionAsInt(-256.52));
console.log(fractionAsInt(256));
```

Comment: Первый вариант с отрицательными не сработает в текущем исполнении

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Спасибо, я знаю. Задача недоопределена, как обычно.

Comment: @Igor немного не то нужно получить не 0.52 а 52

Answer (score 3):

Надо просто взять остаток от деления на единицу.

Однако стоит заметить, что, поскольку вещественные числа не всегда точно представимы, может возникнуть некоторое незначительное отклонения, т. е. перед показом пользователю число стоит округлить до желаемого числа знаков:

```js
console.log(256.52 % 1)
console.log(-256.52 % 1)
console.log(.1 + .2)

console.log((256.52 % 1).toFixed(3))
console.log((-256.52 % 1).toFixed(3))
console.log((.1 + .2).toFixed(3))
```